# TodoList Webpage, better event listener than mouseovert/out? why is my pseudo element ::first-letter not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello and thanks for stopping by.

I have one main problem with my app.
I think the mouseout and mouseover event listeners are firing like crazy when I put my cursor over the trashcan icon and I don't know why. It gets all glitchy and can't click on it correctly.
Any advice?

https://codepen.io/Dali213/pen/ExjLMdG?editors=0110

```
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");

//initialisation
const arr = ["learn how to use GitHub.", "learn how to use GitHub.", "learn how to use GitHub."];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  addToDo(arr[i]);
}

function addToDo(text) {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  const p = document.createElement("p");
  p.textContent = text;
  li.append(p);
  li.addEventListener("click", lineThrough);
  li.addEventListener("mouseover", addTrashCan);
  li.addEventListener("mouseout", removeTrashCan);
  ul.append(li);
}

//add rubish icon+delete function
function del() {
  const li = this.closest("li");
  li.removeEventListener("click", lineThrough);
  li.removeEventListener("mouseover", addTrashCan);
  li.removeEventListener("mouseout", removeTrashCan);
  li.remove();
}

function addTrashCan() {
  const trashCan = document.createElement("i");
  trashCan.classList.add("far", "fa-trash-alt", "trash-can");
  trashCan.addEventListener("click", del);
  this.prepend(trashCan);
}

function removeTrashCan() {
    const trashCan = this.querySelector("i");
    trashCan.removeEventListener("click", del);
    trashCan.remove();
}
```

Second question, at first my pseudo element ::first-letter was working correctly now it isn't.
When I look at the styles applied with the developper tool, it still seems applied though... Why?

Any advice on my code is more than welcome.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could prepend the trash can in the beginning itself and show/hide based on `mouseout` or `mouseover` events instead of creating the element each time:

```css
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```js
function addTrashCan() {
  this.querySelector('i').classList.remove('hidden')
}

function removeTrashCan() {
  this.querySelector('i').classList.add('hidden')
}

function addToDo(text) {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  const p = document.createElement("p");
  const trashCan = document.createElement("i");
  trashCan.classList.add("far", "fa-trash-alt", "trash-can", "hidden");
  trashCan.addEventListener("click", del);
  li.prepend(trashCan);
  p.textContent = text;
  li.append(p);
  li.addEventListener("click", lineThrough);
  li.addEventListener("mouseover", addTrashCan);
  li.addEventListener("mouseout", removeTrashCan);
  ul.append(li);
}
```

```js
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
const input = document.querySelector("input");

//initialisation
const arr = ["learn how to use GitHub.", "learn how to use GitHub.", "learn how to use GitHub."];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  addToDo(arr[i]);
}

function addToDo(text) {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  const p = document.createElement("p");
  const trashCan = document.createElement("i");
  trashCan.classList.add("far", "fa-trash-alt", "trash-can", 'hidden');
  trashCan.addEventListener("click", del);
  li.prepend(trashCan);
  p.textContent = text;
  li.append(p);
  li.addEventListener("click", lineThrough);
  li.addEventListener("mouseover", addTrashCan);
  li.addEventListener("mouseout", removeTrashCan);
  ul.append(li);
}

//hide the input
function hideInput() {
  input.classList.toggle("hidden");
}

//add task to the list
function enter() {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) addToDo(this.value);
}

//line-through on click
function lineThrough() {
  this.querySelector("p").classList.toggle("line-through");
}

//add rubish icon+delete function
function del() {
  const li = this.closest("li");
  li.removeEventListener("click", lineThrough);
  li.removeEventListener("mouseover", addTrashCan);
  li.removeEventListener("mouseout", removeTrashCan);
  li.remove();
}

function addTrashCan() {
  /*const trashCan = document.createElement("i");
  trashCan.classList.add("far", "fa-trash-alt", "trash-can");
  trashCan.addEventListener("click", del);
  this.prepend(trashCan);*/
  console.log('in');
  this.querySelector('i').classList.remove('hidden')
}

function removeTrashCan() {
  /*const trashCan = this.querySelector("i");
  trashCan.removeEventListener("click", del);
  trashCan.remove();*/
  console.log('out');
  this.querySelector('i').classList.add('hidden')
}

//listeners
document.querySelector(".display").onclick = hideInput;
input.onkeyup = enter;
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #18b7e4, #e8e9be);
}

.container {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  min-width: 270px;
  max-width: 270px;
  margin: 80px auto 0px;
}

.head {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #2072b5;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.display,
i {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input {
  border: 2px solid #2072b5;
  width: 246px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

p {
  display: inline;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}

p::first-letter {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

li:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #f7f5f7;
}

li:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.line-through {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.trash-can {
  background-color: red;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}

li {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>to-do list</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fe178342de.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="head">
      <h1>TO-DO LIST</h1>
      <h1 class="display">+</h1>
    </div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Todo" />
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Edit:
To fix the `::first-letter` pseudo element, issue you could add the following css:

```css
li {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer it works perfectly. I don't know why I didn't think of that when I was already using it for the button display ^^"! 
Any idea for the ::first-letter pseudo element problem?

Comment: `::first-letter` will not work with inline elements, in you case the paragraph element is inline

Comment: @baloo you could add `li {
  display: flex;
}` css

Comment: thank you for all these informations. I did something easier, display: inline-block and it works fine !
Thanks again!